# Dynamic related objects django form

Tags: django, django-forms

i currently have models that look like this

```
class Lg(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,choices = LG_CHOICES,unique = True)

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,choices = STATE_CHOICES,unique = True)
    lg = models.ManyToManyField(Lg,related_name ='State_Lg',blank= True,null = True)

class AddPlaceForm(forms.Form):
    house_number = forms.IntegerField()
    street_name = forms.CharField()
    area = forms.CharField()
    city  = forms.CharField()
    lg = forms.ChoiceField(choices = Lg.objects.none()) 

    def __init__(self,state_id,*args,**kwargs):
        super(GenericPropertyForm,self).__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['lg'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=list(State.objects.get(id = state_id).lg.select_related()))
```

I'd like the user to pass in the state id from the view like this `form = AddPlaceForm(state_id)`

can any one pls help with this

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view code:

```
form = AddPlaceForm(state_id=state_id}
```

form

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     state_id = kwargs.pop('state_id', None)
     super(AddPlaceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields['lg'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = ((lg.id, lg.name) for lg in State.lg.filter(id=state_id))
```

Comment: thanks but you have not told me what my lg field will look like

Comment: @DanielRoseman How will the lg field look like and the form thanks any one else can give a hand too thanks

Comment: I edited my answer check it out. Let me know if you find any issues

Comment: @RaunakAgarwal thanks for you help i have not tried to use this yet but with th __int__ come after the other fields or before.Thanks

Comment: @user1711168: I din't really get your question